# How to hide previous image on click of next tab?

Tags: jquery

I have 3 tab. And there image background like slider.On page load first image appear correctly. After page loading, if i click on any tab, then new image background come below previous image without hide previous image. I want if i click on any tab , then image background of tab section should change.My problem is that how to hide previous clicked tab image.Please help me !!

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabIcon" role="tablist">
    <li class="condos">
        <a href="#condos" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="tablink">Condos</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cruises">
        <a href="#cruises" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-ship" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="tablink">Cruises</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="packages">
        <a href="#packages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-suitcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="tablink">Packages</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="flights">
        <a href="#flights" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="tablink">Flights</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cars">
        <a href="#cars" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="tablink">Cars</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="hotel">
        <a href="#hotel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="tablink">Hotels</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>





<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="hotel">
       <content 1>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="cars">
        <content 2>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="flights">
        <content 3>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="condos">
       <content 4>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="packages">
        <content 5>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="cruises">
        <content 6>
    </div>
</div>





<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hotel").click(function () {
        $(".slice1").addClass("imgActive");
    });
    $(".cars").click(function () {
        $(".slice2").addClass("imgActive");
    });
    $(".flights").click(function () {
        $(".slice3").addClass("imgActive");
    });
    $(".packages").click(function () {
        $(".slice4").addClass("imgActive");
    });
    $(".cruises").click(function () {
        $("slice5").addClass("imgActive");
    });
    $(".condos").click(function () {
        $(".slice6").addClass("imgActive");
    });
});
</script>



<!-- images-->
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="~/Content/Images/rccship.png" class="imgSlide slice1 imgActive"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="~/Content/Images/overwaterbungalowsresized-3.png" class="imgSlide slice2"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="~/Content/Images/hiker.png" class="imgSlide slice3"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="~/Content/Images/santorini1.png" class="imgSlide slice4"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="~/Content/Images/airplanerevised.png" class="imgSlide slice5"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="~/Content/Images/beachcondos.png"class="imgSlide slice6"/>
    </li>
</ul>
<!--/images-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code with your js code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hotel").click(function () {
        $(".slice1").addClass("imgActive");
$(".slice6").removeClass("imgActive");
    });
    $(".cars").click(function () {
        $(".slice2").addClass("imgActive");
$(".slice1").removeClass("imgActive");
    });
    $(".flights").click(function () {
        $(".slice3").addClass("imgActive");
$(".slice2").removeClass("imgActive");
    });
    $(".packages").click(function () {
        $(".slice4").addClass("imgActive");
$(".slice3").removeClass("imgActive");
    });
    $(".cruises").click(function () {
        $("slice5").addClass("imgActive");
$(".slice4").removeClass("imgActive");
    });
    $(".condos").click(function () {
        $(".slice6").addClass("imgActive");
$(".slice5").removeClass("imgActive");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks dear for Trying.Your code is not working properly.But i solve it. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".hotel").click(function () {
            $(".slice1").addClass("imgActive");
            $(".slice2, .slice3, .slice4, .slice5, .slice6").removeClass("imgActive");

        });
        $(".cars").click(function () {
            $(".slice2").addClass("imgActive");
            $(".slice1, .slice3, .slice4, .slice5, .slice6").removeClass("imgActive");

        });
        $(".flights").click(function () {
            $(".slice3").addClass("imgActive");
            $(".slice1, .slice2, .slice4, .slice5, .slice6").removeClass("imgActive");

        });
        $(".packages").click(function () {
            $(".slice4").addClass("imgActive");
            $(".slice1, .slice2,.slice3, .slice5, .slice6").removeClass("imgActive");

        });
        $(".cruises").click(function () {
            $(".slice5").addClass("imgActive");
            $(".slice1, .slice2,.slice3, .slice4, .slice6").removeClass("imgActive");
        });
        $(".condos").click(function () {
            $(".slice6").addClass("imgActive");
            $(".slice1, .slice2,.slice3, .slice4, .slice5").removeClass("imgActive");

        });
    });
</script>
```